# Clear data base (Sqlite) on device

Tags: ios, database, swift, sqlite, swift2

I used SwiftData to create sqlite database in swift ,data base worked on simulator but when i want run app on real device it's not work and error is there is not such table, how i can solve this problem?

```
  let fileMan = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        if (fileMan.fileExistsAtPath(dbPath)){
            if let source = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath?.stringByAppendingPathComponent(databaseStr){
                if (fileMan.fileExistsAtPath(source)){

                    print("SQLiteDB - file \(databaseStr) not found in bundle")
                } else {
                  //  var error: NSError?
                    do {
                    try fileMan.copyItemAtPath(dbPath, toPath: source )


                    } catch _ {

                    }

                }

            }

        }
        return dbPath

    }
```

Comment: Please post your full error message.

Comment: @JonasSchafft    During: SQL prepare code1:SQL error or missing database

Comment: Did you load the app on the physical device and then make changes to the SQL database after it was loaded to the physical device? If so try deleting the app then run it again.

Comment: @JonasSchafft I did your suggestion but in device database not work yet , on simulator there is no problem